# Combine Two Videos into One using c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, video, editing

I have a website where users upload videos.  I would like a library or control set to splice two videos into one.  Does anyone have such a thing, or a different strategy?

Answer (score 3):

If you're working with `.flv` videos I can recommend [flvbinder](http://www.flvsoft.com/bind_flv/) command-line utility. The only thing it can do is to bind several `.flv` videos into one. But it is very quick and free.

I used it in my last project through running it in a separate process (`System.Diagnostics.Process`).

Answer (score 2):

A command line tool like ffmpeg would probably be the way i'd go. Anything C# would likely be too slow for video editing.

Comment: Answer to Chris
> c# is not that slow as you think. Remember that
> it can be run at the same speed at c++(GC is in another process so that should no affect it that much). It
> just take time to JIT I agreed but then after that it can run at the
> same speed. But I agree if you need raw access to the memory you should use c++ or c for the job.
And there is tools out there that will make it much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe too late for the original poster, but for other people who want to do something alike I can recommend the Splicer library : http://splicer.codeplex.com/